# how to get previous day datetime at specific hour in oracle sql

Tags: oracle11g

How to get datetime in oracle of previous day at specific hour?

Say for example today is June 1st and i want to get the datetime of previous day 6pm?

i need to go back one day at specific hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to do that, I give you few, if I understand your question correctly:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1), 'YYYY.MM.DD')||' '||'06:00:00','YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS'),
       TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) + 0.25
  FROM dual
```

In first way you get, 05/31, and 06:00:00 is time which you want to use.
In second example you will get last day and add 6/24=0.25 (6 hours of 24)